# Define an enum with the same name as the class its on

Tags: java, class, methods, enums

So i have a class called "Millis" that stores ints called Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond and i need a method called add that can do the following

```
Millis m4 = new Millis(21, 45, 52, 785, 15, 12, 2018); // [21:45:52.785] 15/12/18
m4.add(Millis.DAY, 16);// [21:45:52.785] 31/12/18
m4.add(Millis.HOUR, 2);// [23:45:52.785] 31/12/18
m4.add(Millis.MINUTE, 14);// [23:59:52.785] 31/12/18
m4.add(Millis.SECOND, 7);// [23:59:59.785] 31/12/18
m4.add(Millis.MILLISECOND, 214);// [23:59:59.999] 31/12/18
```

How do i define the parameters of the method add? i thought of using an enum, but i cant name the enum with the same name as the class, or i dont know a workaround for that.

Comment: What's wrong with using different names?

Comment: Why did you quote "Millis"? Is this an assignment for school? Where is the rest of the class? Please tell us everything you can about your requirements. Note that Java already has (some of) this functionality in [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).

Comment: if you insist that you want same name you can use final variables instead.

Comment: @Sweeper the assignment strictly says that i need to call the method that way

Comment: Does it also forces you to use an `enum`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, its an assigment for school, we are basically creating or own Time, and TimeDate classes (sort of)

Comment: @Sweeper Can't be an `enum`. The constructor wouldn't be valid. We need to know all of the details of the assignment.

Comment: @Sweeper no, it doesnt forces us to use an enum, thats just what i thought, what can i use instead? :o

Comment: If you're creating your own `Time` and `TimeDate` classes, **what** is "Millis"? Please explain yourself clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on same name, you can use final variables instead.

```
public class Millis {
final int second =6;
final int minutes =3;
...
}
```

remember that you can not change value of final variables  after assigning values.

```
Millis mill = new Millis(2,3,4);
int myNumber =millis.second;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I like that, but it is a solution:

```java
public class Millis {

    enum Field {
      DAY,
      // ...
    }

    public static final Field DAY = Field.DAY;
    // ...
}
```

<sub>The `enum` can even be declared `private`</sub>

<sub>Note: the `enum` may be in a own file (class), that is, not nested</sub>